# Toy poodle seeking attention

Tags: dogs, behavior, training

My 1 yr old poodle always seeks attention from me when I get home after work (he is usually confined in the kitchen). He will whine non-stop when he sees me and hoping I will let him out.

The reason why we don't let him out is because he will pee and jump at people from excitement. I'm trying to teach him that only when he calms down then we will give him the attention.

He don't usually whines when he is home with my mum even though she confines him sometimes.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you should probably just take the dog outside once you get home, he pees because he is excited but I imagine he actually needs to go after being at home while your at work all day.  As far as the jumping on you problem, you shouldn't give the dog any attention when she jumps on you but wait until she sits and leaves you alone to give attention.  This will teach her that jumping on people does not get their attention.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried to ignore him but he whines non-stop and I feared the neighbours will complain (as I live in an apartment). When I approached him he will starts to pee before I could even unlock the leash.